# Dotnetnuke Workflow Email Notification not working

Tags: dotnetnuke

I tried workflow in DNN 7.0 Pro trial site. Setup with my Gmail account and SMTP working fine. I can receive email user role changes, etc. However, when submit content for approval, approver doesn't get any email and once it's approve/reject, editor also doesn't get any. 
This feature is really important for me.

Is there anyting I missed out to configure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a trial, you should be able to go through the DotNetNuke helpdesk.

If you are using 7.0.1 & 7.0.2, there was an issue wit the message dispatcher on new installs.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Community-Exchange/Question/3273/Notification-API-and-Emails.aspx

Comment: Hi Ventrian, I've read your discussion and configured, scheduler showing 2 messages sent, however emails not receiving. please check screenshot http://postimage.org/image/yc5vqydwt/